# Moving a VM server to another VM environment.

Tags: vmware-esxi

We are divesting ourselves of on division of our company and need to package up one of our VM servers on ESXi-5.0 for transfer to the new entity.

What is the quickest, most reliable method of doing this?

They are also on VMware.

Answer (score 1):

Half a question - we've got the 'from', we need to know the 'to' - although the answer will be "use the .ovf format via the export option' anyway.